# WCF net.tcp connection dies after 9 hours, 1 minute

Tags: wcf

I've got a WCF client talking to a WCF server (on the same machine). We use netTcpBinding with message-level security (using a custom principalPermissionMode and a custom implementation of serviceCredentials). The service is marked with `InstanceContextMode.PerSession`.

The WCF service is self-hosted in a Windows service (not in IIS).

In order to fake keep-alive, we have a `Ping` method that the client calls every 15 seconds. We keep the client proxy open for the lifetime of the client program (because initializing the session is expensive in our case).

Despite this, the connection is dropped after 9 hours, 1 minute and a bit (in 10 test runs, 7 of them died after 9h1m6s).

The only thing of consequence in the WCF logs is a "SocketConnection aborted" message, followed by a varying set of exceptions, but usually including a "connection was in the faulted state" exception.

Is there some timeout in WCF, or in TCP/IP, that's causing this? Because I'm stumped.

Comment: 10 test runs, each taking over 9 hours? I admire your patience.

Comment: In honesty, that's 2 test runs of 4 clients, and 2 at the same time of 1 client. So only 18 hours, and left overnight, anyway.

Comment: If you re-think carefully, `9x3600+60+6<32768`, which is 2 power of 15

Comment: Yeah, but not quite, and even so, where is that coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much tedious investigation: After about 9 hours, the WCF client re-authenticates with the service. Something I'm doing during the authentication step is killing the existing session.

Comment: +1 - I ran into this problem and independently drew the same conclusion. Wish I'd had the benefit of your research first, but I didn't know what to search for. I'm curious what was going wrong with the authentication? In our case we were doing custom authentication and intentionally not allowing the same client to connect twice, which was checked on Validation. So, the re-validation was always failing.

Comment: @JoelLee: Exactly that, but further back. Re-authenticating was killing the previous backend session, which was triggering a `Kicked` event, which was causing me to tear down the WCF session, which killed the client.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments above you were running the tests at the same time.

Were they also on the same server, using the same application pool?

If so a recycling of the application pool could have caused all the tests to stop at the same time.

Comment: Yes, same server. Not using IIS, so no application pools. Asked my QA guy to start the clients staggered, to see if they die at the same time, or just after the same delay.